# Fuzzy Logic to match the records in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-logic, approximate-nn-searching

I have a huge datasets of 2 Million and i want to match the records based on the fuzzy logic I have my original dataframe like

```
+---------+---------------+
|     name|        address|
+---------+---------------+
|   Arvind|      Kathmandu|
|   Arvind|      Kathmands|
|   Arbind|      Kathmandu|
|  Arvinds|      Kathmandu|
|   Arveen|      Kathmandu|
|   Arvins|      Kathmandu|
|   Arvind|Kathmandu Nepal|
| Abhishek|        Pokhara|
|Abhisheks|        Pokhara|
|Abhishek1|        Pokhara|
|Abhishek2|        Pokhara|
|Abhishek3|        Pokhara|
+---------+---------------+
```

I tried using pyspark windows function but windows function takes partition based on the exact match and i want to have may records matched based on the fuzzy logic and wanted to have my output as a dataframe like this:-

```
+---------+---------------+
|     name|        address|uuid_for_match_record
+---------+---------------+
|   Arvind|      Kathmandu| uuid_1
|   Arvind|      Kathmands|uuid_1
|   Arbind|      Kathmandu|uuid_1
|  Arvinds|      Kathmandu|uuid_1
|   Arveen|      Kathmandu|uuid_1
|   Arvins|      Kathmandu|uuid_1
|   Arvind|Kathmandu Nepal|uuid_1
| Abhishek|        Pokhara|uuid_2
|Abhisheks|        Pokhara|uuid_2
|Abhishek1|        Pokhara|uuid_2
|Abhishek2|        Pokhara|uuid_2
|Abhishek3|        Pokhara|uuid_2`
```

How can it be achieved based on the huge 2Million datasets
Here is the image of my dataframe and what i want to achieve:
[image of dataframe and output i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeSvV.png)

Comment: There are plenty of fuzzy matching algorithm... any idea of the one you want to use ?

Comment: @Steven token_set_ratio

Comment: Don't do a NxN where N=2Million comparisons. First cluster your data and only check for exact similarity within the clusters.

Comment: @user238607 can you explain with your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken inspiration from this blogpost to write the following code.

https://leons.im/posts/a-python-implementation-of-simhash-algorithm/

The `cluster_names` function just clusters the strings within the list based on the `cluster_threshold` value. You can tweak this value to get good results. You can also play around with `shingling_width` in `name_to_features`. You can create features of width=2,3,4,5 and so on and concatenate together.

Once you are satistifed your with your clusters, then you can further do `fuzzywuzzy` (this library has been renamed to `thefuzz`) matching to find more exact matches.

https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz

First install `simhash` python library, then run the following code.

`pip install simhash`

```
from simhash import Simhash


def simhash_distance(hash1, hash2):
    return hash1.distance(hash2)


def name_to_features(name, shingling_width=2):
    name = name.lower()
    return [name[i:i + shingling_width] for i in range(len(name) - shingling_width + 1)]


def cluster_names(names_list, cluster_threshold=20):
    clusters_internal = []
    name_hashes = [(name, Simhash(name_to_features(name))) for name in names_list]

    for name, hash_val in name_hashes:
        found_cluster = False
        for cluster_ele in clusters_internal:
            if simhash_distance(cluster_ele['centroid'], hash_val) <= cluster_threshold:
                cluster_ele['names'].append(name)
                found_cluster = True
                break
        if not found_cluster:
            clusters_internal.append({'centroid': hash_val, 'names': [name]})
    return clusters_internal



names = ["Alice", "Alicia", "Alise", "Alyce", "Bob", "Bobb"]
clusters = cluster_names(names)
for i, cluster in enumerate(clusters, 1):
    print(f"Cluster {i}: {cluster['names']}")

data = [
    "Arvind Kathmandu",
    "Arvind Kathmands",
    "Arbind Kathmandu",
    "Arvinds Kathmandu",
    "Arveen Kathmandu",
    "Arvins Kathmandu",
    "Arvind Kathmandu Nepal",
    "Abhishek Pokhara",
    "Abhisheks Pokhara",
    "Abhishek1 Pokhara",
    "Abhishek2 Pokhara",
    "Abhishek3 Pokhara"
]

clusters_data = cluster_names(data)
for i, cluster in enumerate(clusters_data, 1):
    print(f"Cluster {i}: {cluster['names']}")
```

Output :

```
Cluster 1: ['Alice', 'Alicia', 'Alise', 'Alyce']
Cluster 2: ['Bob', 'Bobb']
Cluster 1: ['Arvind Kathmandu', 'Arvind Kathmands', 'Arbind Kathmandu', 'Arvinds Kathmandu', 'Arveen Kathmandu', 'Arvins Kathmandu', 'Arvind Kathmandu Nepal']
Cluster 2: ['Abhishek Pokhara', 'Abhisheks Pokhara', 'Abhishek1 Pokhara', 'Abhishek2 Pokhara', 'Abhishek3 Pokhara']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation which does the same thing. This time using MinHash and LSH.

Here's an article which explains this.

https://spotintelligence.com/2023/01/02/minhash/

First, install `datasketch` and `networkx`

`pip install networkx`

`pip install datasketch`

```
import networkx as nx
from datasketch import MinHash, MinHashLSH
import pprint
import random
names = [
    "Arvind Kathmandu",
    "Arvind Kathmands",
    "Arbind Kathmandu",
    "Arvinds Kathmandu",
    "Arveen Kathmandu",
    "Arvins Kathmandu",
    "Arvind Kathmandu Nepal",
    "Abhishek Pokhara",
    "Abhisheks Pokhara",
    "Abhishek1 Pokhara",
    "Abhishek2 Pokhara",
    "Abhishek3 Pokhara"
]

# just to test stuff
random.shuffle(names)
print(f"shuffled names list = {names}")
def get_shingles(name_arg):
    name_internal = name_arg.lower()
    shingle_list = [2, 3, 4]
    list_given = []
    for shingle_width in shingle_list:
        list_internal = [name_internal[i:i + shingle_width] for i in range(max(len(name_internal) - shingle_width + 1, 1))]
        list_given.extend(list_internal)

    return set(list_given)

signatures = {}

for name in names:
    m = MinHash(num_perm=128)
    for shingle in get_shingles(name):
        m.update(shingle.encode('utf8'))
    signatures[name] = m


lsh = MinHashLSH(threshold=0.5, num_perm=128)
for name, minhash in signatures.items():
    lsh.insert(name, minhash)

G = nx.Graph()

for name in signatures.keys():
    similar_names = lsh.query(signatures[name])
    for sim_name in similar_names:
        G.add_edge(name, sim_name)


clusters = list(nx.connected_components(G))


pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
print("Final results:")
pp.pprint(clusters)
```

Output :

```
shuffled names list = ['Arvind Kathmands', 'Arvins Kathmandu', 'Abhishek3 Pokhara', 'Abhishek1 Pokhara', 'Abhishek2 Pokhara', 'Arvind Kathmandu', 'Arvind Kathmandu Nepal', 'Arbind Kathmandu', 'Abhisheks Pokhara', 'Arvinds Kathmandu', 'Arveen Kathmandu', 'Abhishek Pokhara']
Final results:
[ { 'Arbind Kathmandu',
    'Arveen Kathmandu',
    'Arvind Kathmands',
    'Arvind Kathmandu',
    'Arvind Kathmandu Nepal',
    'Arvinds Kathmandu',
    'Arvins Kathmandu'},
  { 'Abhishek Pokhara',
    'Abhishek1 Pokhara',
    'Abhishek2 Pokhara',
    'Abhishek3 Pokhara',
    'Abhisheks Pokhara'}]
```