Fuzzy Join on Venue Names Based on City
I am working with PySpark and need to join two datasets based on the city and a fuzzy matching condition on the venue names. The first dataset contains information about stadiums including a unique venue_id, while the second dataset, which I receive periodically, only includes venue names and cities without the venue_id.
I want to join these datasets to match the venue_name from the incoming data to the existing dataset using fuzzy logic (since the names are not always written identically), and then pull the corresponding venue_id.
Existing Dataset (df_stadium_information):



venue_name
city
venue_id




Sree Kanteerava Stadium
Bengaluru
1


Sree Kanteerava Stadium
Kochi
2


Eden Gardens
Kolkata
3


Narendra Modi Stadium
Ahmedabad
4



Incoming Data (df_new_stadium_data):



venue_name
city




Sri Kanteerava Indoor Stadium
Bengaluru


Eden Gardens
Kolkata



Desired Output:



venue_name
city
venue_id




Sri Kanteerava Indoor Stadium
Bengaluru
1


Eden Gardens
Kolkata
null



I want the output to show the venue_id from df_stadium_information if there is a fuzzy match on venue_name and an exact match on city. If there's no fuzzy match, the venue_id should be null.

https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal you can use java UDF in pyspark

There is also some stuff in python https://github.com/openvenues/lieu?tab=readme-ov-file#running-on-sparkelasticmapreduce

I have provided two solutions using MinHash and LSH.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186018/fuzzy-logic-to-match-the-records-in-a-dataframe/78192904#78192904

you've explained what you want to do, but not actually asked a question

Your desired example is incorrect as there is a match of Eden Gardens in Kolkata with a venue_id of 3.
First we create our dummy tables.
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ref_tbl (
    venue_name STRING,
    city STRING,
    venue_id INT
  );

INSERT INTO ref_tbl VALUES
('Sree Kanteerava Stadium','Bengaluru',1),
('Sree Kanteerava Stads','Bengaluru',2),
('Sree Kanteerava Stadium','Kochi',3),
('Eden Gardens','Kolkata',4),
('Narendra Modi Stadium','Ahmedabad',5),
('Sree Kanteerava Stadium','Bangalore',6);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE IN_TABLE (
    venue_name STRING,
    city STRING
  );

INSERT INTO IN_TABLE VALUES
('Sri Kanteerava Indoor Stadium','Kolkata'),
('Eden Garden','Kolkata'),
('Sri Kanteerava Stadium','Bengaluru');

Install the python package called rapidfuzz
pip install rapidfuzz

Then register it as a spark udf function
from rapidfuzz import fuzz
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,IntegerType,DoubleType
    
def fuzzyrapid(s1, s2):
    return (fuzz.token_sort_ratio(s1,s2))

spark.udf.register("fuzztest",  fuzzyrapid,DoubleType())

Select the distinct combinations of venue name and city.
%sql
-- Select distinct cities from the input file/table
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW v_distinct_input_names 
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT venue_name as input_name,city FROM IN_TABLE;

SELECT * FROM v_distinct_input_names;

Do a crossjoin so you get all combinations with the same city
%sql
-- cross join the distinct cities with the lookup table 
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW v_crossjoin 
AS 
SELECT A.venue_name as ref_name,  A.city as city, Input_name FROM ref_tbl A CROSS JOIN v_distinct_input_names B where A.city = B.city;

Now execute the custom spark udf to get the similarity score and do a windowing function to get the best score for a single combination
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW vw_fuzzy1 AS
SELECT ref_name, Input_name, city, fuzztest(ref_name,Input_name) AS similarity_score FROM v_crossjoin;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW v_fuzzy2 AS 
 SELECT ref_name, Input_name, city, similarity_score
 FROM
 (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY input_name ORDER BY similarity_score DESC) as RowNum, *
     FROM vw_fuzzy1
 ) 
 WHERE RowNum = 1;

Now you can do a join to get the venue id. You need to define a score threshold for your usecase. In my case I've used 70.
%sql
SELECT input_name, B.venue_name, A.city,
case
when similarity_score > 70
  then venue_id
else
  null
end as venue_id
from v_fuzzy2 A left join ref_tbl B on A.ref_name = B.venue_name AND A.city=B.city;

Your result will be

